# Use ORM methods, to get the required data?

Tags: odoo

I need to get the value of field in a tree view of the fields_view_get method and a
I use ORM methods to achieve this. my code :

```
 class res_partner(osv.osv):

_inherit = 'res.partner'


def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):


    if context is None:
        context = {}

    partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    ids_partner = partner_obj.search(cr, uid, [], context=context)              
    partner_name = partner_obj.browse(cr, uid, ids_partner, context=context)
    element = partner_obj.browse(cr,uid,ids_partner[0]).numcte

    res = super(res_partner,self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)


    newcte=test_name.numcte


    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])

    if view_type == 'tree':

        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='numcte']"):
               node.set('string', 'numcte')
        for node in doc.xpath("//button[@name='icono']"):
               node.set('icon', newcte) 

    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res


_columns = {
    'numcte': fields.text('numero cliente'),
}

 res_partner()
```

My problem is when I, use for instance :

```
 element = partner_obj.browse(cr,uid,ids_partner[0]).numcte
```

It returns me the value of the field that I want, but in the treeView is the same for each row, like this A001, A001, A001, in instead of A001, A002, A003.

in this case  ids_partner[0], How can I make this number to be dynamic and changing for each row ?

Or in the case that  use this:

```
 my_data  = partner_obj.read(cr, uid, ids_partner, ["numcte"], context=context)
```

returns me the tuple like this:

[{'numcte': u'A001', 'id': 3}, {'numcte': u'A002', 'id': 2}, {'numcte': u'A003', 'id': 4}]
[{'numcte': u'A001', 'id': 3}, {'numcte': u'A002', 'id': 2}, {'numcte': u'A003', 'id': 4}]
[{'numcte': u'A001', 'id': 3}, {'numcte': u'A002', 'id': 2}, {'numcte': u'A003', 'id': 4}]

one for each row

How can I get the value of the field that I want for the correct row. ?

thank you all for your time, I been a while in this so any help is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

`fields_view_get` is provided to allow you to change/create the XML that defines the view, not the data.

What you need to do in `fields_view_get` is drop your field onto the view.  However, overriding `fields_view_get` is only done in very unusual cases where you need the view to by dynamic in a way that can't be achieved easily with attrs and states in the XML view.

The usual pattern is to create a view in XML that extends the partner tree view and adds your field in the correct place using an XPATH expression.  If your field is a new field, you will need to also need to create a new model that inherits the res_partner model and add your new field in _columns.